# How to shift focus from one text box to another in QtQuick?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

The code creates two input text boxes:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Column 
{
  width: 500
  height: 200

  Text 
  {
    id: userInfoTextA
    focus: false
    text: "Enter a value from 0 to 10:"
  }

  TextInput
  {
    id: userInputA
    focus: true

    anchors.left : userInfoTextA.right
    anchors.leftMargin : 20

    validator: IntValidator { bottom:0; top: 20 }

    Keys.onReturnPressed: 
    {
      console.log (userInputA.text)
    }
  }

  Text 
  {
    id: userInfoTextB
    focus: false
    text: "Enter a value from 10 to 20:"
  }

  TextInput
  {
    id: userInputB
    focus: true

    anchors.left : userInfoTextB.right
    anchors.leftMargin : 20

    validator: IntValidator { bottom:0; top: 20 }

    Keys.onReturnPressed: 
    {
      console.log (userInputB.text)
    }
  }
}
```

In the output window the focus, by default, is set to the text box A. **How should I move the focus to text box B by:

1. Keyboard

2. Mouse**
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, lots of little things:

1) When you click with the mouse it should already shift focus; no need to worry about that.

2) Your layout is difficult in column format, and by default the TextInput had no width which makes it hard to use

3) **the real answer**: You can set the focus on an item to switch it (see below)

4) But you should probably also use the KeyNavigation system too, also seen in the example below, as people are used to using tab/shift-tab for switching between items.

So, here's some modified example code that does what you want:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Grid 
{
  width: 500
  height: 200
  columns: 2

  Text 
  {
    id: userInfoTextA
    text: "Enter a value from 0 to 10:"
    width: 200
  }

  TextInput
  {
    id: userInputA
    focus: true
    width: 100

    anchors.left : userInfoTextA.right
    anchors.leftMargin : 20

    validator: IntValidator { bottom:0; top: 20 }

    KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
    KeyNavigation.tab: userInputB

    Keys.onReturnPressed: 
    {
      console.log (userInputA.text)
      userInputA.focus = false
      userInputB.focus = true
      event.accepted = true;
    }
  }

  Text 
  {
    id: userInfoTextB
    text: "Enter a value from 10 to 20:"
    width: 200
  }

  TextInput
  {
    id: userInputB
    width: 100

    anchors.left : userInfoTextB.right
    anchors.leftMargin : 20

    validator: IntValidator { bottom:0; top: 20 }

    KeyNavigation.priority: KeyNavigation.BeforeItem
    KeyNavigation.backtab: userInputA

    Keys.onReturnPressed: 
    {
      console.log (userInputB.text)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You said: `When you click with the mouse it should already shift focus; no need to worry about that.` Actually, I cannot see a text box there (with my code) so I don't konw where to click.